# Is it possible to have a custom address for Contact Forms in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, express

Instead of the Wordpress contact form sending to an email, is it possible to have it sent to a custom backend server?

Such as http://localhost:3000 where my nodejs express server is being hosted?

Answer (score 0):

in wp-config.php  add following settings - As a result wp_mail() will work.

```
define( 'SMTP_HOST', 'server.a2hosting.com' );  //  Check your hosting  company 
define( 'SMTP_AUTH', true );
define( 'SMTP_PORT', '465' );
define( 'SMTP_SECURE', 'ssl' );
define( 'SMTP_USERNAME', 'user@yourdomain.com' );  // Username for SMTP authentication
define( 'SMTP_PASSWORD', 'password' );          // Password for SMTP authentication
define( 'SMTP_FROM',     'user@yourdomain.com' );  // SMTP From address
define( 'SMTP_FROMNAME', 'Yourfirstname YourLastname' );         // SMTP From name
```

```
use following code in your form template or function.php , you may need custom function to pull each field data 

wp_mail("recipient@example.com", "Subject", "Message");
```